# Extract JSON from multi-part HTTP response

Tags: java, json

I'm working with a HTTP web service that returns json in a multi part response. Are there any libraries that can help me parse the JSON from the multipart response? Here is the example of what the response looks like I want to extract "{SOMEJSON}" and "{ANOTHERJSON}"

```
--Boundary_11484410_1140855603_1483010655979
Content-Type: application/json
Content-RequestId: SaveMessage
Status-Code: 200
Content-RequestDuration: 146

{SOMEJSON}
--Boundary_11484410_1140855603_1483010655979
Content-RequestId: Status
Content-Type: application/json

{ANOTHERJSON}
--Boundary_11484410_1140855603_1483010655979--
```

Comment: Use your BOUNDRY in the request: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary_11484410_1140855603_1483010655979`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I don't understand. How does that help me extract the JSON separately?

Comment: The boundary marks the beginning/end of the next request in the multi-part request.